# facebook like button only showing up when logged in

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

For some reason the Facebook like button is only showing up when logged in on my site.

Here is the link http://www.your90s.com/, and the behavior is repeated through out every post on my site.

I'm pretty sure the issue is on my end but I haven't been able to figure it out yet. I am using the "Really simple Facebook Twitter share buttons" plugin for wordpress, but the behavior seems to be emulated with about any plugin I use.

Any thoughts or input are appreciated.

I should clarify that when I say "It only shows up when logged in, I mean logged in to Facebook"

Cheers

Comment: The facebook like button shows for me

Comment: On facebook? Or what?